# How to query url in azure search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I store document with following fileds in azure search, and all of then are searchable filed.

- url (example: https://example.com/test.html or http://www.example.com/doc/doc1.html)
- title
- content

According to offical document [search document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents) , I try to query by url with content's keyword is hotel but fail.

```
POST /indexes/hotels/docs/search?api-version=2017-11-11  
{  
  "search": "url:example.com AND hotel",  
  "searchMode": "all"  
}
```

**Update:**

I have try to use standard tokenizer, and the domain name **blog.xuite.net** success parser as token.

```
 "tokens": [
    {
        "token": "https",
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 5,
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "blog.xuite.net",
        "startOffset": 8,
        "endOffset": 22,
        "position": 1
    },
    {
        "token": "yundestiny",
        "startOffset": 23,
        "endOffset": 33,
        "position": 2
    },
    {
        "token": "20050916",
        "startOffset": 34,
        "endOffset": 42,
        "position": 3
    },
 ]
```

Why can I search by **url:blog.xuite.net** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figure out to use **CustomAnalyzer** by tokenizer = standard_v2 and tokenFilters 
= LimitTokenFilter. Following is my index setting.

```
 "analyzers": [
    {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
        "name": "domain_analyzer",
        "tokenizer": "standard_v2",
        "tokenFilters": [
            "my_limit"
        ],
        "charFilters": []
    }
],
"tokenizers": [],
"tokenFilters": [
    {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.LimitTokenFilter",
        "name": "my_limit",
        "maxTokenCount": 2,
        "consumeAllTokens": false
    }
],
```

By use this CustomAnalyzer, the **url** field  for example

```
https://example.com/test.html
```

will be index as **example.com** only.

So I can search by search=url:(example.com) AND {keyword}

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you might want to try is to apply a [custom analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers) to the field that contains this content.  I actually think the uax_url_email tokenizer would work well for your situation, but another option is to create an analyzer that tokenizes on characters such as // and / using Char Filters.

Comment: Can you give more example how to create and apply a custom analyzer